# How to access web service client from jar file?

Tags: java, web-services, jakarta-ee, package

I am new to the web service world. I am able to create a JAX-WS web service client using IBM RAD 7.5 successfully. The client is wrapped up in a war file then in an ear file. I have a class in the same war file to call the client with the following code with no issue:

```
MyService service = new MyService();
IMyService port = service.getPort(IMyService.class);
Response res = port.doThings(request);
```

Now I want to process the response in a shared jar to be re-used in the same ear. But I start to see java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Response.
My question is how can the classes in war be visible to jar in the same ear? Did I miss some configuration in MANIFEST.MF? in web.xml? in application.xml? or Should I assemble the web service client in a jar file instead of war?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You can make your code actually look like code by indenting them with four spaces. Also, it's discouraged to write "Thanks" at the end of a question - could you [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/38558492/edit) yours to remove that?

Comment: So put the common client classes in a jar, then share as you stated between that war and other application.

Comment: dorukayhan, Thank you for pointing out. I have edited as requested. This is my first post. Please pardon my format. I will keep in mind.

Comment: OldProgrammer, this might be a good idea. I can give it a try. So it seems putting the jar inside war may be the only way to go.